# Javascript works only on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

So, yea, i have some long long script, which is really simple, so let's me just cut off not-necessary fragments that doesn't change anything.
Problem is, that javascript is working only on firefox. I tried it on google chrome, IE, Opera - didn't work. My friends tried too and yea, same.
Problem is that i searched miles of internet and couldn't find reason why i got stuck.
Maybe you are smart enaugh to know what's going on.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('option').click(function() {     
        var currentdi =  document.getElementById('currentdi').value;
        var currentle = document.getElementById('currentleague').value; 
               var aimdi = document.getElementById('aimdi').value;
        var aimle = document.getElementById('aimleague').value;     
if (currentdi == "bronze"){
            if (currentle == "1"){
            var wart = "125";
            }else if (currentle == "2"){
            var wart = "100";
}
if (aimdi == "silver"){
            if (aimle == "1"){
            var wart2 = "300";
            }else if (aimle == "2"){
            var wart2 = "265";
}
var roznica = wartosc2-wartosc;
        if (roznica < 25){
        $('#valuation').text('Sorry, not possible');
        }else{
        $('#valuation').text(roznica);
        }

        return false;
    });
    });
```

And HTML:

```
<form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select id="currentdi" class="categorylist" name="currentname">
        <option value="bronze" selected>Bronze</option>
        <option value="silver">Silver</option>      
    </select>
    <select id="currentleague" class="categorylist" name="currentnumber">
        <option value="1">Division I</option>
        <option value="2">Division II</option>
        </select>

    </form>
<div id="aimdiv">           
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select id="aimdi" class="categorylist" name="aimname">
        <option value="bronze" selected>Bronze</option>
        <option value="silver">Silver</option>  
    </select>
    <select id="aimleague" class="categorylist" name="aimnumber">
        <option value="1" selected>Division I</option>
        <option value="2">Division II</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

So yeah, that's all, still trying to get it worked on other browsers... but don't know how.

Please, can you help me?

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: 1.9.1 actually, but hey. There was a comment that said me to change it from "onclick" to "change" and it worked. Don't know who it was, but if you can add this as answer it'll be great so i could choose your comment as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your handler from "onclick" to "change" =)